# How do I search related values in Yii2?

Tags: search, yii2

I have the following situation in Yii2:

- Project model
- CustomField, defining a custom field type and whether it should be applied to Projects (other options are employees and companies)
- CustomFieldContent, related to both an entity (project in this case) and a custom field type

So, an example:

`Project with id 1
CustomField with id 2
CustomFieldContent with entityId = 1, type = 'project', customFieldId = 2 and value = 'test'`

Now, displaying custom content for each project in Yii's gridview is no problem. But, I want to make it searchable and sortable. Therefore, I need to add the custom field name as an attribute to ProjectSearch. That, however, can't be done as Yii doesn't allow for dynamic attributes.

Any ideas as to how to go about this?

Comment: You should simply read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations

Answer (score 0):

For searchable and sortable content  i suggest you this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/) where you can find useful sample for build what you need. ( the scenario nuber 2 is the more appropriate to your needs)

In short term, you should extend your base model adding the relation you need, setup in searchModel proper functions adding to the dataProvider->setSort for the field/relation and add the where condition for filtering.

below a short extract

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
    'attributes' => [
         .... 
        'yourRelatedField' => [
            'asc' => ['field1' => SORT_ASC, ],
            'desc' => ['field1' => SORT_DESC,],
            'label' => 'your Laber',
            'default' => SORT_ASC
        ],
    ]
]);
```

and extending the where condition for filtering.

```
/* Add your filtering criteria */

// filter CustomFieldContent
$query->joinWith(['table_a' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('table_a.CustomFieldContent LIKE "%' . $this->CustomFieldContent . '%" ');
}]);
```